# DB grid : How to use a column of the current row of one as an index into another?

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I am not sure if the question title is clear enough, please feel free to edit it.

Basically, I have two DB grids which reflect two database tables, each grid showing one.

When the user selects a row in the first table (let's call it `oders`), I want to update the second with details of any rows matching a column of the selected row of the first table.

Say, for instance that table `orders` has a column `customer_id` and I want to populate the second table (let's call it `order_details`) with details of all orders from that customer, one order per row.

I can connect up 2 @ datasource, query and connection to the two `TDbGrid`s, but I am stuck as to how to code `order_details` SQL.

The SQL for `orders` is just `SELECT * from orders`, but the other?

I want something like `SELECT * from order_details WHERE cutomer_id=<orderQuery>.currentRow.FieldByName("customer_id").AsInteger` - but I don't know how to do that ...

Can someone help me with some Delphi code?

Also, once I set up that relationship, will selecting a new row in the `orders` DB grid automatically update the `order_details` DB grid? Or do I need to add code for that.

P.s I know that there is no `books` tag anymore (more's the pity), but can someone recommend a good book which explains the fundamentals of programming DB aware controls? I obviously need one. Thanks

Comment: It's so called master detail relationship and [`here's`](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa071001a.htm) a tutorial for this topic. Maybe [`this part`](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa071001c.htm) might be interesting for you, maybe not.

Comment: As far as the book recommendation, that question is off-topic here. This isn't a book referral engine. However, any of the older books (those by [Cantú](http://www.marcocantu.com), for instance) have chapters on database programming that are a very useful reference for most versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parameterized query for the detail (child) database:

```
SELECT * FROM Order_Details od WHERE od.CustomerID = :CustomerID
```

Then set the child query's `MasterSource` to the parent (`Order`) datasource, and the `MasterFields` to `CustomerID`. (If there are multiple columns that link the two, separate them by `;`, as in `CustomerID;OrderNumber`.)

Every time you scroll the parent (change the selected record in the parent DBGrid), the child query will be executed with the ID of the parent row passed as a parameter automatically.

Comment: It has been along time since I awarded this answer. Actually I implemented this manually. In the OnClick() handler of the master, I set a parameter of the "salve" query, which does the same thing. Revisitng this question, I thought that I woudl do it your way and find that the query has a `MasterSource` property, but no `MasterField` (Delphi XE2 starter edition, using AnyDac)

Comment: Sorry; I don't use AnyDac, and there's nothing in your question above or the tags that say you're using it. What does their documentation say about `MasterSource`? You  also haven't mentioned which DBMS you're using, so I can't even try and find it for you because I don't know what query component you're using.

Comment: According to their [documentation](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/uADCompDataSet_TADDataSet.html), `TADDataSet` indeed does contain a `MasterFields` property, and is used just as I described above.